# Llamar una ventana Framework desde un proyecto C# WPF .NET 6.0 (VS2022 Prof)

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy con un proyecto usando C# WPF .NET 6.0 (VS2022 Prof). En la misma solución, necesito crear un proyecto .Net Framework 4.8 (o parecido) y diseñar un par de ventanas de trabajo. Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo hago para llamar desde WPF .NET 6.0 a las ventanas que están creadas en el proyecto de .NET Framework 4.8? Llevo muchos días buscando y no encuentro ningún ejemplo. Me gustaría me ayudaran, ya que esto depende que pueda concluir mi trabajo. Saludos a todos y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: como que ventanas... no entiendo que queres hacer.. una libreria, tal vez, con sus propias ventanas?

Comment: Revisa aquí https://copy-paste.online/?code=1977

Comment: Hola gbianchi, para llamar una ventana WPF sería de la siguiente forma:

Comment: Excelente ejemplo Yussef, muy agradecido por tu ayuda y tu valioso tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Días atrás hice un ejercicio parecido te comparto como lo hice.

1. Generé un proyecto secundario, en tu caso sería el de .NET Framework 4.8.

Ojo solo crea el proyecto en la misma solución no intentes hacer referencia ya que te marcara error.

2. Realice todos los que necesita hacer mi programa secundario y en program.cs agregue que pueda recibir parámetros por si es necesario compartir información entre sistemas. Para hacerlo use el siguiente código:

   ```
   //Se genera una variable llamada Parametros en program para poder llamarlo desde 
   //cualquier parte del proyecto.
   public static string[] Parametros;
   [STAThread]

   //Al Main se agrega que puede recibir parametros con 'params string[] args'
   static void Main(params string[] args)
   {
     //Para hacer pruebas puedes usar este codigo y generar los datos de manera 
     //manual. Cuando exportes tu proyecto para uso de usuario, mandalo en 
     //releace y no se usen los de prueba
     #if DEBUG
          args = new string[] { "BD", "Estancia", "Usuario", "Password", "RFC" };
     #endif
     // Los parametros recibidos se almacenan en la variable global que creamos
     Parametros = args;

     Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new Generador());
   }
   ```
3. Ahora en el proyecto principal para llamar el programa se usa el siguiente codigo

   ```
   public void LlamarProgramaExterno()
   {
     var exe = new Process();
     //Aquí muestro como generar y mandar los parámetros para el sistema secundario. 
     //Si no lo requieres mandar parametros manda así 'ProcessStartInfo(RutaExe, "")'
     var conf = Properties.Settings.Default;

     var Info = new ProcessStartInfo(RutaExe, $"{conf.ServidorSql} {conf.InstanciaSql} {conf.UsuarioSql} {conf.PasswordSql} {_Seleccion.EmpresaActual.RFC}")
     {
        UseShellExecute = false
     };

     exe.StartInfo = Info;
     //Fin de exclucion.
     exe.Start();
     exe.WaitForExit();

     //A partir de aquí el código se ejecutará hasta que cierres la ventana del otro sistema.
   }
   ```
4. El 'RutaExe' es una variable string global el cual lo asigno de la siguiente manera.

   ```
   #if DEBUG
   //Ruta para las pruebas este es el debug del sistema secundario
     private readonly string RutaExe = @"D:\Users\User\Desktop\Secundario\Secundario.exe";
   #else
     private readonly string RutaExe = @"Secundario.exe";
   #endif
   ```

Y de esta forma ejecutas el proyecto con diferentes .NET

Nota: Cuando generes tu instalador expórtalo en modo release y los ambos proyectos deben estar en la misma carpeta para que se ejecuten bien. Espero este metodo te ayude fue la forma en que le di solución.

Comment: Perdona la tardanza Jonathan, pero me parece excelente tu repuesta. Voy a probar y te cuento que tal me va. Muy agradecido por tu tiempo.